# Java - Dynamically create vertex

Tags: java, mysql, vertex

I need some help whit creating dynamically vertex in Java. I get the data from a MySQL database, so far I have this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM coordinates";

Statement st = conn.createStatement();         
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);      
while (rs.next())
{
  int id = rs.getInt("id");
  String vert = Integer.toString(id);

  //Which approach will work?        
  Vertex vert = new Vertex(vert);          
}
st.close();
```

This is how the vertex should looks like:

```
Vertex 1 = new Vertex("1");
Vertex 2 = new Vertex("2");
Vertex 5 = new Vertex("5");
Vertex 8 = new Vertex("8");
//...and so on...
```

**EDIT**

So I did this, is ok?:

```
Map<String, Vertex> map = new HashMap<>();
while (rs.next()){
  int id = rs.getInt("id");
  String id_vertex = Integer.toString(id);          
  map.put("X" + id, new Vertex(id_vertex));      
}
```

But now I have to create my vertex right?

At the end I would need to create edges also, because I need this for a Dijkstra Algorithm..so I am creating edges like this:

```
X151.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge( X3957,261),new Edge( X3589,194)};
```

The main problem was, that i was getting this error:`The code of method main(String[]) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit`

Am I doing right, will this solve my problem, or is my idea completely wrong?

Comment: a `List` or a `Map` should be your go to. But juding your question you are rather out for a `Map`

Answer (score 1):

You can try it using the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

```
Map<String, Vertex> map = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    map.put("v" + i, new Vertex(str[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ca n do this as combination of List and set. For example check this below code:

```
int intArray[] = new int[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    intArray[i] = 5;
}

List<Integer> lists = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    lists.add(5);
}

Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    map.put("n" + i, 5);
}
```

In the list or map you can use any type to store the data. For your case you want to store vertex so you can use vertex type instead of Integer or String.

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering the vertices on a separate thread.

```
//sql query
ResultSet datas = ...

Thread newThread = new Thread(
    Public Void run(){
           //process datas into verts
           //for elem in data
           ArrayList<Vert> list...
           // add to list

           Algorithm(list)
    }
}

newThread.start();

Void Algorithm(ArrayList<..> data){

          //run algorithm here
          //so on forth
    }
```